# HtmlUnit WebClient resets thread interruption status

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt, htmlunit, executorservice

I have a bunch of parser classes that subclass a PriseParser class  and implement a getAllPrices() method (called by the PriseParser.getPrices() that does some other stuff too not related to this post) in order to acquire some data from various web sites. Below is an example for such an implementation:

```
@Override
public List<Price> getAllPrices() throws ParserException,
        InterruptedException {

    LogFactory.getFactory().setAttribute("org.apache.commons.logging.Log",
            "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");

    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit")
            .setLevel(Level.OFF);
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.commons.httpclient")
            .setLevel(Level.OFF);

    List<Price> prices = new ArrayList<price>();

    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_24);

    HtmlPage page;
    try {
        page = webClient.getPage(URL);

        if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){

            System.out.println("INTERRUPTED BEFORE CLOSE");
        }

        //my parsing code here that fills prices list. Includes calls to webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript in some places


        webClient.closeAllWindows();

        if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){

            System.out.println("INTERRUPTED AFTER CLOSE");
        }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ParserException(e);
    }

    return prices;
}
```

These parsers are run concurrently with an ExecutorService:

```
public List<Price> getPrices(List<PriceParser> priceParsers) throws InterruptedException {

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors
            .newFixedThreadPool(PriceParsers.size());

    Set<Callable<List<Price>>> callables = new HashSet<Callable<List<Price>>>();

    List<Price> allPrices = new ArrayList<Price>();

    for (PriceParser PriceParser : PriceParsers) {

        callables.add(new Callable<List<Price>>() {
            public List<Price> call() throws Exception {

                List<Price> prices = new ArrayList<Price>();

                prices = PriceParser.getPrices();

                return prices;
            }
        });
    }

    List<Future<List<Price>>> futures;

    try {
        futures = executorService.invokeAll(callables);

        for (Future<List<Price>> future : futures) {

            allPrices.addAll(future.get());
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        throw e;

    } catch (ExecutionException e) {

        logger.error("MULTI-THREADING EXECUTION ERROR ", e);
        throw new RuntimeException("MULTI-THREADING EXECUTION ERROR ", e);

    } finally {

        executorService.shutdownNow();
    }

    return allPrices;
}
```

The two `if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){}` pieces of code in the first method, were added in order to check the following issue I have observed: When the executor service is interrupted (this can happen from a gui application that terminates the thread when pressing a cancel button), the first interruption check I inserted in my code successfully prints "INTERRUPTED BEFORE CLOSE".

However the second check does not print anything. It seems therefore that somehow one of the calls to webClient I make (which are waitForBackgroundJavaScript method calls and the webClient.closeAllWindows() call at the end) clears the thread interruption status. Can someone explain why is this actually happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem lies in a call to webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript performed by my parsing code. Internally this goes as far as waitForJobs method of HtmlUnit's JavaScriptJobManagerImpl method. And this method contains the following piece of code that essentially swallows all InterruptedExceptions and therefore the ability for any caller to be able to identify if any interruptions were made during that call:

```
                try {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        wait(end - now);
                    }

                    // maybe a change triggers the wakup; we have to recalculate the
                    // wait time
                    now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
                catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                    LOG.error("InterruptedException while in waitForJobs", e);
                }
```

Instead of catching and just logging, it should just let the exception be thrown